# Move T&C above payments methods in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I am trying to move the Terms and Conditions above the payment methods options. I tried couple of snippets I found here, but no luck, as most of them moves the payment methods above the order summry, but what am trying to achieve is:

Also I remove the current and then add a manual text one, as my website is running multilanguage and I can not register the simple text in WPML to translate it.

- Order Summary.
- Terms and Condition box.
- Payment Methods
- Submit button.

Any help is appreciated.